# State flow to render

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to pass state to a function in the render, so every click I get a result.
I'm checking if the state is passed to the console.log and I get Undefined, why?
(Edit: the minNum and maxNum will be changed over time so I want to treat them as state and not parameters).

```
class Generator extends React.Component {
    constructor (props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { 
        onView: '0',
        minNum: 0 ,
        maxNum: 100
      } 
    }

  render() {

    const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;

    const btnClick = (minNum, maxNum) => {
      console.log(minNum);
     }

  return (
    <div className="container">
    <Instructions />
    <Range 
      max={this.state.maxNum} 
      min={this.state.minNum} 
      />
    <Generate currentClick={btnClick}/>
    <View show={this.state.onView}/>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Generator;
```

Comment: you are getting Undefined in console.log(minNum); .Am i Right??

Comment: btnClick function should be outside of render method

Comment: on your case, minNum is a function param instead of state destructed value

Comment: I believe if you want the values of the parameters to default to the state values (not sure why, since you could just reference them directly _inside_ the function) you could give them as default values: `const btnClick = (minNum = minNum, maxNum = maxNum)`. Though that's just awkward, I think it's better to revisit why you're providing parameters, but then not passing any arguments

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if Im wrong but maybe this would be the simpler solution

```
const Generator = () => {
  const [onView,setView] = useState("0")
  const [minNum,setminNum] = useState(0)
  const [maxNum,setmaxNum] = useState(100)

  const btnClick = (minNum, maxNum) => {
    console.log(minNum)
  }
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Instructions />
      <Range max={maxNum} min={minNum} />
      <Generate currentClick={() => btnClick(minNum)} />
      <View show={onView} />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Generator
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not define functions inside `render` as it will hurt performance and can easily cause rendering errors. What you can do is to access state values directly when defining the `onClick` callback:

```
btnClick = () => {
    const { minNum, maxNum } = this.state;

    console.log(minNum);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Instructions />
        <Range max={this.state.maxNum} min={this.state.minNum} />
        <Generate currentClick={this.btnClick} />
        <View show={this.state.onView} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Well this would give me ('btnClick' is not defined) error if I use it before the render method.

Comment: It depends when and how it's used.

Comment: Can you expain what you mean by "when and how it's used"?

Comment: What I mean is you need to show how you're using it and what do you mean by 'if I use it before the render method'. The way it's defined in the answer will make it an instance method of the component, so you can't use it outside of this component, otherwise it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the function outside of render since it causes issues with performance,
and pass the minNum as parameter inside of arrow function on click like this :

```
<Generate currentClick={() => this.btnClick(minNum)}
```